# How to revoke user permission when use ms access 2003 mdw security. And assigned permission to group

Tags: security, ms-access, ms-access-2003

When use mdw security, User and Group are stored in system.mdw, and permissions are stored in mdb file.

If I assigned permissions to group, When I want to revoke permissions of a user,I can remove the user from the groups.But if user keep the previous system.mdw file , He can still access the mdb file.

How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to do this. In NTFS security, DENY permission supersedes ALLOW, but with Jet user-level security, it doesn't. So, there's no way to deny the user permission on an object as long they remain a member of any group that has permissions on that object.

The only solution is to distribute the updated workgroup file. Normally, a mult-user application will SHARE a workgroup file, stored in the same place as the back-end data file, so there is no issue at all. However, I've seen cases where it was more efficient to store the workgroup file locally. In that case, you have to come up with a mechanism for updating the workgroup file. [Tony Toews Front-End Updater](http://autofeupdater.com/) is one such solution.